# how to get last records of unique usernames from an array in java script

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an Array of Objects Like:

```
[ 
 { id: 8, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-10-14'},
 { id: 1, username: 'harry' ,weight:80,date:'2019-01-01'},
 { id: 2, username: 'harry' ,weight:84,date:'2019-02-21'},
 { id: 3, username: 'john' ,weight:80,date:'2019-03-11'},
 { id: 7, username: 'john' ,weight:80,date:'2019-05-25'},
 { id: 4, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-08-06'},
 { id: 5, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-06-11'},
 { id: 6, username: 'harry' ,weight:90,date:'2019-04-03'}


]
```

and I want last record of every unique user datewise for ex:

```
 [ 
 { id: 6, username: 'harry' ,weight:90,date:'2019-04-03'},
 { id: 7, username: 'john' ,weight:80,date:'2019-05-25'},
 { id: 8, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-10-14'},
]
```

in javascript.

Comment: How did you attempt to solve this problem yourself, and what went wrong? Please post your "*[mcve]*" code.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get the values.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, username: 'harry', weight: 80, date: '2019-01-01' }, { id: 2, username: 'harry', weight: 84, date: '2019-02-21' }, { id: 3, username: 'john', weight: 80, date: '2019-03-11' }, { id: 4, username: 'peter', weight: 80, date: '2019-08-06' }, { id: 5, username: 'peter', weight: 80, date: '2019-06-11' }, { id: 6, username: 'harry', weight: 90, date: '2019-04-03' }, { id: 7, username: 'john', weight: 80, date: '2019-05-25' }, { id: 8, username: 'peter', weight: 80, date: '2019-10-14' }],
    result = Array.from(new Map(array.map(o => [o.username, o])).values());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the array from end for current object `username` and previous object `username`. If they are same break the loop, else push in the array.

```js
const input =  [ 
      { id: 1, username: 'harry' ,weight:80,date:'2019-01-01'},
      { id: 2, username: 'harry' ,weight:84,date:'2019-02-21'},
      { id: 3, username: 'john' ,weight:80,date:'2019-03-11'},
      { id: 4, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-08-06'},
      { id: 5, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-06-11'},
      { id: 6, username: 'harry' ,weight:90,date:'2019-04-03'},
      { id: 7, username: 'john' ,weight:80,date:'2019-05-25'},
      { id: 8, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-10-14'},
];

const output = [];

for(let i = input.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
      if(input[i].username === input[i-1].username) {
          break;
      }
      output.push(input[i]);
}

console.log(output.sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date.localeCompare)));
```

Comment: I want the result datewise ,array is not sorted..Please check the question,i have updated

Comment: not getting the expected result,Where have you sorted the result date wise in the loop.You are not getting my question.I just not only want the unique user records but also last record of unique user sorted date wise in asc order.

Comment: @M.K - I guess I misinterpreted your question. So, basically you want all unique objects, and in case for duplicate username, last object you want. Most of the solutions provided gives desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Maps and Sets inherently only hold unique values. You can use this as following:

```js
var myMap = [ 
 { id: 1, username: 'harry' ,weight:80,date:'2019-01-01'},
 { id: 2, username: 'harry' ,weight:84,date:'2019-02-21'},
 { id: 3, username: 'john' ,weight:80,date:'2019-03-11'},
 { id: 4, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-08-06'},
 { id: 5, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-06-11'},
 { id: 6, username: 'harry' ,weight:90,date:'2019-04-03'},
 { id: 7, username: 'john' ,weight:80,date:'2019-05-25'},
 { id: 8, username: 'peter' ,weight:80,date:'2019-10-14'},
]

var result = {};
for(i = 0; i < myMap.length; i++){
 result[myMap[i]['username']] = myMap[i];
}

console.log(Object.values(result));
```